# Downcrossing inequality of submartingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

On page 14 of "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" by Karatzas and Shreve, (iii) of theorem 3.8, the book has the downcrossing inequalities for a submartingale

$$ED_{[\sigma,\tau]}(\alpha,\beta;X(\omega))\leq\frac{E(X_\tau-\alpha)^+}{\beta-\alpha}$$  where $\{X_t,\mathcal{F}_t;0\leq t<\infty\}$ is a submartingale whose every path is right continuous, $[\sigma,\lambda]$ is a subinterval of $[0,\infty)$, $\alpha<\beta$ and $\lambda>0$ are real numbers.

The book claims Chung's probability theory book theorem 9.4.2 proves the discrete time version. But when I looked it up, Chung's book only has upcrossing for submartingales and downcrossing for supermartingales (see theorem 9.4.3). Can anyone give a reference for downcrossing of submartingales? Or perhaps this is a mistake of the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fewer downcrossings than upcrossings if $X_0 < \alpha$ and at most one more if $X_0 \ge \alpha$, so once you bound upcrossings you've also bound downcrossings.

Comment: I see, in that case should we add 1 on the right hand side of the equation?

Comment: @Simplyorange Yes, probably, unless there was a mention at some point that $X_0 < \alpha$.